# How can I trigger runs for actual Emails which arived before enabling Logic App?

Tags: email, triggers, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logical App which uses the **when a new email arrives (V3) - trigger**
[image: email-trigger]

the problem is that e-mails which are new and unread will not proccessed by the  LogicApp if they arrived before I enabled the Logic App.

What could I do to trigger or retrigger  runs for this emails.

or is that the problem the webhook trigger **when a new email arrives (V3)** nad I should use the polling Trigger (V2).

So all advices  for retriggering on V3-trigger or change app to v2 or other proposals are very welcome.

Comment: I don't think the trigger(v2 and v3) can implement your requirement of trigger by the received email before you enable the logic app. I can just be triggered when receive new email after you enable the logic app.

Comment: If you want to check the unread email which received before enable the logic app, you can add an action "[Get emails(V3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#get-emails-(v3))" after the trigger and enable "[Fetch Only Unread Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad99D.png)"

Comment: The idea i had last week too. But i think it is no unproblematic
 in a normal workflow trigger be e-mail then he gets all unread mails inside the work flow.
For a seperate Logic App  with different enabled time it is good idea.
I think I search for  a better option or a strong filtered get_emails.

The best case for me were a way to get the the emails with get_emails to trigger them again with a http request.

Comment: If you find a better solution,  please post an answer in below area for other communities reference.

Comment: @HuryShen: you are right proccesing mail new mails which recieive in disabled state is not  planned from microsoft.
I am not sure but i think last year with  V2 trigger it worked but now  I cannot create a workflow with V2 Trigger.  Ican change it in Logic Appcode and then i  see it changed in designer but it doesn't save parameters for polling intervall.

Should i anwser my request itself that there is no direct solution. or should i wait till an user answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test and summarize from the comments, it seems we didn't understand the "**when a new email arrives (V3)**" trigger correctly. I do some more test for the trigger and find the feature with two situations:

**1.** If we create the trigger(or create the Office365 connection) first but disable the logic app, then receive an email, then enable the logic app. It can be triggered by the received email.

**2.** If receive the email first, then create the trigger(or create new Office365 connection in logic app). The logic app can't be triggered by the received email.

In a word, only the emails received after the creation time of Office365 connection, the logic app can be triggered.

===============================**Update**================================

If you think it is not guaranteed, you can do it by "**Get emails**" action to get all of the unread emails.

Comment: Microsoft say it is not planned that the logic app should be disabled in production setting and only in enabled state mails can received.
So first case, i had somtimes similar cases where it worked  in disabled state and some cases where it doesn't work. Ithink it is not guaranteed and we better should do the things you proposed e.g. this or other Options:.

- write an cleanup app after for calling at ending the disabled state
- call get emails(). in the logic app  for processing unread messages

Comment: Hi @ingo_ww If you think it is not guaranteed, you can also do it by "Get emails" action in your logic app. I have updated my answer. By the way, I guess you have raised a support ticket  to azure support team, so I think you can reply the support mail to ask them if the trigger can be triggered while the Office365 connection was created before the email received(as the first situation I mentioned).

Comment: I will ask if I have time, but get_emails is problematic in my workflow.
possible is  getall unread mails before date x (set filter) and this branch should only run on monday mornings.
I had last time many exceptions (Unexpected Error) on 30 mails in same minute on monday. so and then in this workflow doing and getting unread emails too. the flow is made fore handling 1 mail at same time. then e.g. handling 20 in the same flow.
for that i need an extra logic app or this must be nestet  uand unread mails must checked in parent logic app. All my known possible ways are not really good.

Comment: @ingo_ww Since this problem was almost solved and the solution could not be improved, could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Comment: it worked for me, thanks I will nowasked microsoft if is reliable and how can it works with different deployment types. Or can I recreate this behaviour?
If i get actual news I will post it.